# El puntero no me regresa el valor completo de la cadena

Tags: c, punteros

Hola tengo problemas con este código que debe convertir un entero a binario e ir guardando los ceros y los unos en un puntero de tipo char. Sin embargo luego de la ejecución el puntero solo me devuelve un 1 y no todos los valores de la cadena

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int * permutaInt;

char * permuta(char * str, int x, int base) {
    int division = x;
    int posicion = 0;
    int *copia;

    while (division != 0) {

        str[posicion] = 48 + (division % base);
        division = division / base;
        posicion++;
    }

    posicion = 0;

    while (str[posicion] != '\0') {
        posicion++;
    }

    copia = (char*) malloc(posicion * sizeof (char));

    posicion = posicion - 1;
    int contador = 0;

    while (posicion != -1) {
        copia[contador] = str[posicion];
        posicion--;
        contador++;
    }
    copia[contador++]='\0';
    contador=0;

    return copia;

}

int main() {

    char *str;
    char *recibido;
    str =(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    int x = 0;
    int base = 2;
    int contador=0;

    printf("Ingresa tu numero \n");
    scanf("%d", & x);



    recibido=permuta(str, x, base);
    printf("%s",recibido);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo el porqué `x = 0` en la función `main()`y luego ese valor lo pasas como parámetro a `permuta()`en donde lo asignas a `division`. Lo que veo es que debido a esto no se ejecutará la conversión a binario.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que, en lugar de *1 función que lo haga todo*, uses varias, siguiendo el principio de *responsabilidad única*; te sera mas fácil tanto el desarrollar el código como el posible depurado. Sin hablar de poder usar cada *parte* en códigos futuros ...

- `char *int2bin( int x, int base )`: convierte un número a la base indicada, devolviendo una cadena de texto que se reserva dentro de la propia funcion.

Es un *copia*/*pega* de tu código :-)

Una posible mejora (la está pidiendo a gritos) es que, en lugar de un tamaño fijo para la cadena de salida, reserve lo justo que va a utilizar.

- `char *strrev( const char *orig, char *dst )`: *invierte* una cadena de texto. `orig` es la cadena original, y `dst` (que puede ser `NULL`) es la cadena resultado. **NO** se puede usar la misma cadena como origen y destino, ojo ;)

Si `dst == NULL`, la función reserva internamente una cadena del espacio justo necesario.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *int2bin( int division, int base ) {
  char *str = malloc( 50 );
  int posicion = 0;

  while( division != 0 ) {
    str[posicion] = 48 + ( division % base );
    division = division / base;
    posicion++;
  }

  str[posicion] = 0;

  return str;
}

char *strrev( const char *or, char *dst ) {
  size_t orsize = strlen( or );

  if( !dst ) dst = malloc( orsize + 1 );
  char *target = dst;

  char *idx = or + orsize - 1;

  while( idx >= or ) {
    *target = *idx;
    ++target;
    --idx;
  }

  *target = '\0';

  return dst;
}

int main( void ) {
  int x;

  printf( "Introduzca un número entero positivo: " );
  scanf( "%d", &x );

  char *bin = int2bin( x, 2 );
  char *rev = strrev( bin, NULL );

  printf( "Entero: %d, binario: %s, invertido: %s\n", x, bin, rev );

  return 0;
}
```